# How to destroy an object at a certain moment?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have an object, when I approach it I have a Button:

```
    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Wood"))
        {
          click.SetActive(true);
        }
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку вызывается метод Attack();

```
    public void Attack()
    {
        line.SetActive(true);
        cut_.isCooldown = true;
    }
```

If cooldown == true , then this is done:

```
    void Start()
    {
        image = GetComponent<Image>();
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        isCooldown = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        CutWood();
    }

    public void CutWood()
    {
        if (isCooldown)
        {
            image.fillAmount -= 1 / cooldown * Time.deltaTime;
            Player.speed = 0;
            if (image.fillAmount <= 0)
            {
                ResetTimer();
                Player.speed = 3;
                isCooldown = false;
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }


    public void ResetTimer()
    {
        image.fillAmount = 1;
    }
```

So here I want when the image.fill Amount == 0 this object was destroyed next to which I am standing